# Is perf sampling reliable in arm Linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, cpu-architecture, arm64, perf

I wrote a demo to test the reliability of perf and there is a strange thing which I can't explain, my demo code:

```
int main(){
    while(1){
        asm("nop");
        asm("nop");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

assembly code:

```
0000000000400554 <main>:
  400554:       d503201f        nop
  400558:       d503201f        nop
  40055c:       17fffffe        b       400554 <main>
```

I ran this program and perf with following command:

```
./a.out
perf record -p `pidof a.out` -F 4000
```

After a while, I got the result which is about several billion lines by `perf script`:

```
perf script -F ip
```

the output is like:

```
           400558
           400558
           400558
           400558
           ......
```

What confuse me is that there is no `40055c` in the output, most output are `400558` and `400554` is far more less than `400558`, as far as I know, perf is based on nmi interrupt which is random for `a.out` program, so there shouldn't be so much difference between `400554`, `400558` and `40055c` in the output of `perf script -F ip`, that makes me doubt about the reliability of perf, Is perf sampling reliable? How to explain the result? My os is on cloud:

```
ctyun@0000000g-jI8sZbV8lk:~/temp$ uname -a
Linux 0000000g-jI8sZbV8lk 4.19.0-arm64-desktop #5312 SMP Mon Nov 7 14:20:02 CST 2022 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

The hardware is a HUAWEI Kunpeng 920, with Taishan v110 cores (based on Cortex-A72. A72 is a 3-wide out-of-order exec core. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-A72)

Comment: What CPU are you running on?  Cortex-A76 or something that's wide enough to run 1 iteration per cycle?  If so, the pipeline state is probably the same most cycles, so it's somewhat understandable that the instruction picked to get the "blame" for that sample is the same.  (And BTW your `uname` output suggests AArch64 / [arm64], not 32-bit ARM.)

Comment: @PeterCordes, it's [HUAWEI Kunpeng 920](https://www.hisilicon.com/en/products/Kunpeng/Huawei-Kunpeng/Huawei-Kunpeng-920) which is based on  ARMv8.2

Comment: IIUC `0x40055c` is `return 0` and before you run endless loop, so that `return 0` is unreachable, so you don't see it

Comment: ARMv8.2 is the architecture version.  I asked about the **micro**architecture, which governs things like how many instructions it can execute per clock cycle.  (And whether adjacent NOPs get folded into one slot in the pipeline, or if NOPs get dropped entirely during decode.)  According to https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/hisilicon/kunpeng/920-6426, the [taishan v110 microarchitecture](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/hisilicon/microarchitectures/taishan_v110) is a custom core based on Cortex-A72.  A72 is a 3-wide out-of-order exec core. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-A72)

Comment: @PeterCordes, could this explain "`400554` is far more less than `400558`"?

Comment: @k1r1t0, no, `0x40055c` is part of the while loop, it has nothing to do with `return 0`

Comment: Yes, especially folding multiple NOPs into one could explain that.  Maybe after an interrupt or something it doesn't always happen.  But IDK if that core does that; check an optimization manual to find out how the pipeline in A72 handles NOPs, or try an experiment with other instructions; hand-written asm makes that easy, like `add w1, w2, w2` ; `add w0, w2, w2`.  (Or a taishan v110 optimization / microarchitecture manual if you can find one.)

Comment: @PeterCordes, tks, why don't you post an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Because I don't know how A72 handles NOPs!  *If* it collapses multiple NOPs into one pipeline slot, that *could* be the main reason for this behaviour.  But it might be some other mechanism, maybe just how a 3-wide pipeline lines up with a 3-instruction loop.  That's why you should go read an A72 optimization guide / microarchitecture manual, or hope that someone else does and writes an answer for you.  Experimenting with non-`nop` instructions would be useful for anyone that might answer.